# The $L_\infty$ norm of the derivative of the $L_2$ spline projector

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory, interpolation, splines

A. Shadrin ([Acta Mathematica, 2001](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485891429)) shows that the $L_\infty$ norm of the $L_2$ projector $P_\Delta$ onto the spline space $S_k(\Delta$) is bounded independently of the knot-sequence. I.e. for a constant $C_k$ that only depends on the order of the spline space (not $\Delta$)

$$ \| P_{\Delta}(f )\|_\infty \leq C_k \| f\|_\infty.$$

Hall & Meyer ([J. Approx. Theory, 1976](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045(76)90040-X)) show for $f \in C^4[a,b]$ and a mesh $a = x_1, \ldots x_n = b$  with $h = \max x_{j+1} - x_j$  then for $\pi f$ a cubic spline interporlant over the mesh then for some constants $C_k$

$$ \| (f - \pi f)^{(r)} \|_\infty \leq C_r \|f^{(4)}\|_{\infty}h^{4-r} \quad 0 \leq r \leq 3$$

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain rates when $h \to 0$ for
$$\| (f - P(f))^{(r)} \|_\infty$$

This could be easily obtained if a result such as the first one holds for higher derivatives i.e  $$\|P(f)^{(r)}\|_\infty \leq C_{k,r}\|f^{(r)}\|.$$

Partial results are also useful. Could be for quadratic or cubic splines and for first or second derivative.